# How to Install Ubuntu Desktop on RAID 1

Tags: raid, mdadm

I am having to rebuild my Ubuntu MYTHTV system (RAID 1) on new hardware due to power supply failure taking out major components (originally built on Feisty). I understood that RAID support was being added to ubiquity at 12.10. I have seen further comments that raid support has been removed from Ubiquity.

There appears to be 2 options to installing Ubuntu Desktop on RAID:-

1) Install Ubuntu server 14.04 and add Ubuntu Desktop via apt-install.

2) Install Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop from alternative disk and upgrade to 14.04.

If RAID support is being added to ubiquity then option 2 would be the better long term solution as it would be repeatable at a later date, and I do not know what other support issues there will be with server involved. 
If RAID support is not being added then option 1 would be the better solution as 12.04 will not be available much longer.

Can you advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquity does not yet have support for raid so you have to manually install `mdadm` and use  it to configure the raid, then choose "something else" in ubiquity and set the raid array to be used as your root filesystem.  Then after the install finishes you need to manually mount the array, chroot into it, and install `mdadm` there:

```
sudo -s
#partition the two disks ( assumed to be sda and sdb ) first
mdadm --create /dev/md0 -l 1 -n 2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
mount -t ext4 /dev/md0 /mnt
mdadm --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
for f in proc sys dev dev/pts run ; do mount --bind /$f /mnt/$f ; done
chroot /mnt
apt-get install mdadm
exit
cp -a /etc/mdadm.conf /mnt/etc/
update-initramfs
for f in proc sys dev dev/pts run ; do umount /mnt/$f ; done
umount /mnt
exit
```

Comment: Thanks psusi.  Had to make a few changes though. The raid config file is /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, and I finished up just doing the detail scan straight into this file. Also needed to chroot back into /mnt before doing the update-initramfs.  Still couldn't get it to work though as after reboot it went into grub with an error that the mduuid couldn't be found. I googled this and now realise that also need to run update-grub but having seen the lack of success that other people had with this I gave up and tried the server install.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you can get raid support during install without knowing anything about mdadm with the server(minimal) installer.

Just download Ubuntu server and install what is required.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

You can then easily install unity with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Tried installing Ubuntu desktop on top of server but their are network configuration issues which I don't seem to be able to solve from the GUI and have no idea how to resolve from the command line.